# add new key frames for each bone in FBX file (c++)

Tags: c++, animation, fbx

I am a newbie in FBX SDK. I am using version 2013.2 .  I am currently importing a FbxScene from a file. what i want to do is to add new keyframes for translation , rotation and scaling for each of the bones in the scene.please help me.
thanks.